# Query Pandas DataFrame distinctly with multiple conditions by unique row values

Tags: performance, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with event logs:

```
eventtime, eventname, user, execution_in_s, delta_event_time
```

The eventname e.g. can be "new_order", "login" or "update_order".

My problem is that I want to know if there is `eventname == "error"` in the periods between `login` and `update_order` by distinct user. A period for me has a start time and an end time.
That all sounded easy until I tried it this morning.

For the time frame of the 24h logs I might not have a pair, because the login might have happened yesterday. I am not sure how to deal with something like that.

`delta_event_time` is a computed column of the eventtime minus the executions_in_s. I am considering these the real time stamps. I computed them:

```
event_frame["delta_event_time"] = event_frame["eventtime"] - pandas.to_timedelta(event_frame["execution_in_s"], unit='s')
```

I tried something like this:

```
events_keys = numpy.array(["login", "new_order"])
users = numpy.unique(event_frame["user"])

for user in users:
    event_name = event_frame[event_frame["eventname"].isin(events_keys) & event_frame["user" == user]]["event_name"]
```

But this not using the time periods.

I know that Pandas has `between_time()` but I don't know how to query a DataFrame with periods, by user.

Do I need to iterate over the DataFrame with `.iterrows()` to calculate the start and end time tupels? It takes a lot of time to do that, just for basic things in my tries. I somehow think that this would make Pandas useless for this task.

I tried `event_frame.sort(["user", "eventname"])` which works nicely so that I can see the relevant lines already. I did not have any luck with `.groupby("user")`, because it mixed users although they are unique row values.

Maybe a better workflow solution is to dump the DataFrame into a MongoDB instead of pursuing a solution with Pandas to perform the analysis in this case. I am not sure, because I am new to the framework.

Comment: Please provide example data for your DataFrame.

Comment: What do you mean `.groupby('user')` did not work for you? I have never had `groupby` fail on me. Please provide a sample data, even if it is purely made up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pseudocode for what I think will solve your problem. I will update it if you share a sample of your data.

```
grouped = event_frame.groupby('user')  # This should work.
#     I cannot believe that it didn't work for you! I won't buy it till you show us proof!
for name, group in grouped:
    group.set_index('eventtime')  # This will make it easier to work with time series.
    #     I am changing index here because different users may have similar or
    #     overlapping times, and it is a pain in the neck to resolve indexing conflicts.
    login_ind = group[group['eventname'] == 'login'].index
    error_ind = group[group['eventname'] == 'error'].index
    update_ind = group[group['eventname'] == 'update_order'].index 

    # Here you can compare the lists login_ind, error_ind and update_ind however you wish.
    #     Note that the list can even have a length of 0.
    # User name is stored in the variable name. So you can get it from there.
```

Best way might be to create a function that does the comparing. Because then you can create a dict by declaring `error_user = {}`.
Then calling your function inside `for name, group in grouped:` like so: `error_user[name] = function_which_checks_when_user_saw_error(login_ind, error_ind, update_ind)`.